# How to avoid printing in last line on every page for a particular command?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, page-breaking, books

I am facing a minor issue the story heading text which is in `\story{#1}` is print in last line in one of the page, so how do i tell to latex if it finds the text from `\story{}` in last line then it will print to next page. Without modifying the document part, Only by modifying somtheing in the preamble part.
Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,11pt,openany]{book}

 \usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{titletoc} %%% Table of contents 
 \usepackage{ebgaramond}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{paracol}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark} %% display chapter in header
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
   \fancyhead[C]{\thepage} %% To display numbering on every page alternately left and right


 \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
 \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
 \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
 \usepackage[colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}



 %%%% End Add
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand\versenumcolor{red}
 \newcommand\chapnumcolor{red}
 \renewcommand\paragraph{%
   \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                 {.25ex \@plus.25ex \@minus.1ex}%
                 {-.5em}%
                 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{\versenumcolor}}}%
 \newlength{\biblechapskip}
   \setlength{\biblechapskip}{1em plus .33em minus .2em}
 \newcounter{biblechapter}
 \newcounter{bibleverse}[biblechapter]
 \renewcommand\chaptername{Book}
 \let\ltx@chapter=\chapter
 \let\ltx@paragraph=\paragraph
 \newcommand{\book}[1]{%
   \gdef\currbook{#1}
   \ltx@chapter{#1}}
 \newcount\biblechap@svdopt
 \newenvironment{biblechapter}[1][\thebiblechapter]
   {\biblechap@svdopt=#1
   \ifnum\c@biblechapter=\biblechap@svdopt\else
     \advance\biblechap@svdopt by -1\fi
   \setcounter{biblechapter}{\the\biblechap@svdopt}
   \refstepcounter{biblechapter}
   \lettrine{\color{\chapnumcolor}\lower-6pt\hbox{\thebiblechapter}}{}\ignorespaces}
   {\vspace{\biblechapskip}}
 \renewcommand{\verse}[1][\thebibleverse]{%
   \refstepcounter{bibleverse}
   \markright{{\scshape\currbook} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}
   \ifnum\c@bibleverse=1\else
     \ltx@paragraph*{#1}\fi}%
 \makeatother


 \newcounter{jChapter}
 \newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{
 \noindent\scalebox{2.5}{\color{red}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.3mm}}
 \setcounter{jChapter}{#1}
 }  
 \newcommand{\jverse}[1]{\noindent\textcolor{cyan}{\scalebox{1.0}{\textbf{#1\hspace{1.0mm}}}}\markboth{\scshape Mathiu\ \thejChapter : #1}{} }
 \newcommand{\story}[1]{\vfill\centering\it\textbf{#1}}



 \title{Translation}
 \date{}
 \author{}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \newcommand{\BookLine}{ \centering\noindent\rule{19cm}{1pt}}
 \newcommand{\BookNote}[1]{{\begin{center} \textbf{KEPACHINI} \justify

 #1
 \end{center}
 \BookLine
 \vspace{2mm}
 }}

 \newcommand{\ParallelLText}[2]{\begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy \switchcolumn[0]\noindent  #1 \switchcolumn[1]\noindent #2 \end{paracol}}

 \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} %%% To restart footnote numbering on every new pages




 \usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}


 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %set depth of printed table of contets.

 \makeatletter


 \patchcmd{\l@section}
   {\hfil}
   {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep     mu$}\hfill}
   {}{}

 \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
     \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname
         \@mkboth{%
            \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
     \printlist{toc}{}{}
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \end{multicols}%
     }

 \makeatother %print dots in sections in toc.


 \begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}

 \frontmatter
 \maketitle
 {\setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Barim\hfill~\\[2.5ex] }
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \tableofcontents
 }
 \mainmatter

 {\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \part*{\scshape Kechejok Barim}
 }
 \pagenumbering{arabic}  
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
 \setcounter{page}{1}



 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}

 \clearpage
 \setcounter{page}{1}


 {\pagestyle{empty}
 {\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \part*{\scshape Kechejok Kemi}
 }

 \frontmatter
 \setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Kemi\hfill~\\[2.0em]}
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \tableofcontents

 \mainmatter
 }
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}

 \ParallelLText{\jverse{4}Alangli det adang kurusar kethe lapen aron thekser atum aphan pangrumpetsi arjulo, “Khristo pirthe kehacheji adim kodakma?” }{\jverse{4}and calling together all the chief priests and scribes of the people, he inquired of them where the Messiah was to be born. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{5}Latum alangliphan thaksi pulo, “Ha Judia adet, Bethlehem arongsopi along. Pima ha montri ketok tekang lapuson helo; }{\jverse{5}They told him, “In Bethlehem of Judea; for so it has been written by the prophet: }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{6}‘Judia adet a-Bethlehem, nanglike Judia adet kedo arongsopi kethe hei hei angbong akebineilo, lapu kali; pima nangli pen keja abang vangji, alangli ne rat, Israel aphan pangriji.’ ” }{\jverse{6}‘And you, Bethlehem, in the land of Judah, are by no means least among the rulers of Judah; for from you shall come a ruler who is to shepherd my people Israel.’” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{7}     Ansi Herod kethek kere atum aphan hangjoisi halabangso achiklo-longso keklangcheng ahut alamjir arju pamelo.  }{\jverse{7}Then Herod secretly called for the wise men and learned from them the exact time when the star had appeared. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{8}Lapen latum aphan ha Bethlehem toisi pulo, “Damra labangso a-oso aphan ridam pamenon. Lapen nanglitum la thekdam long-lote neli jokta damsi kardomkhrup thekji aphan neli long chevoira nethan thunon.”  }{\jverse{8}Then he sent them to Bethlehem, saying, “Go and search diligently for the child; and when you have found him, bring me word so that I may also go and pay him homage.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{9}Latum recho alam arjudetsi damlo, lapen latum la keklangcheng ahut kethek-long achiklolongso latum aphrang aphrang damthusi hala oso kedo adim angdenchit an kele pen sangkok ketik ke dambomlo.  }{\jverse{9}When they had heard the king, they set out; and there, ahead of them, went the star that they had seen at its rising, until it stopped over the place where the child was. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{10}Halatum chiklolongso thek-longsi aning arong parpik-lo.  }{\jverse{10}When they saw that the star had stopped, they were overwhelmed with joy. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{11}Latum hem lut damsi oso lapen apei Meri aphan thek-long-lo, lapen latum akengphu patongruisi alangliphan ardomlo. Ansi latum akhi atelup chepursi alangliphan ning keme pen ser, hijung aphik lapen kenempru ajangthu adan hei hei pilo.  }{\jverse{11}On entering the house, they saw the child with Mary his mother; and they knelt down and paid him homage. Then, opening their treasure chests, they offered him gifts of gold, frankincense, and myrrh. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{12}Lapen Herod along damthuri pu Arnam ahukum amang pen longthusi latum atovar kaprek pen amethang adet chevoijuilo. }{\jverse{12}And having been warned in a dream not to return to Herod, they left for their own country by another road. }
 \ParallelLText{\story{Ijip Adet Kekat}}{\story{The Escape to Egypt}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{13}Latum chevoidet pen mamat Hemphu apherangke Joseph aphan amang pen cheklangsi pulo, “Thurra oso lapen apei aphan cheponra ha Ijip adet katnon, lapen neli nangliphan pupetik ke hadak-le donon; pima Herod ke kepavirjisi oso aphan riji dokdok-lo.”  }{\jverse{13}Now after they had left, an angel of the Lord appeared to Joseph in a dream and said, “Get up, take the child and his mother, and flee to Egypt, and remain there until I tell you; for Herod is about to search for the child, to destroy him.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{14}Alangli thursi ajo amat oso lapen apei aphan cheponsi Ijip adet kat-lo,  }{\jverse{14}Then Joseph got up, took the child and his mother by night, and went to Egypt, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{15}lapen Herod thithetik an latum hadaksi dobomlo. Lake Hemphu pen ajok ha montri kepu tekang, “Neli neli sopo aphan Ijip adet pen hang-lo,” pu alam kechekokji aphanlo. }{\jverse{15}and remained there until the death of Herod. This was to fulfill what had been spoken by the Lord through the prophet, “Out of Egypt I have called my son.” }
 \ParallelLText{\story{Bethlehem A-osomar Atum Aphan Kepathi}}{\story{The Massacre of the Infants}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{16}Ansi kethek kere atum alangliphan pachereitang-lo pu chinisi Herod jasemet aning thilo, lapen alangli Bethlehem lapen adung arei kedo ningkan hini arta lapen ningkan hini pen kekom arta pinso a-osomar atum aphan kepavirkoiji ahukum pilo lake alangli alangli long kevang-akethek kere atum pen chiklolongso keklang alamjir karjulong ahut ateng pensi klemlo.  }{\jverse{16}When Herod saw that he had been tricked by the wise men, he was infuriated, and he sent and killed all the children in and around Bethlehem who were two years old or under, according to the time that he had learned from the wise men. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{17}Ansi Jeremiah montri kepu alam chekok-lo, atheke alangli pulo: }{\jverse{17}Then was fulfilled what had been spoken through the prophet Jeremiah: }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{18}“Ha Ramah angbong ne kechiru chernap ase arjulong-lo; Rachel amethang asomar atum pen apot chiru chernap-lo; alangli aning kepliji aning hanghelo, athema halatum thikoilo.” }{\jverse{18}“A voice was heard in Ramah, wailing and loud lamentation,Rachel weeping for her children; she refused to be consoled, because they are no more.” }
 \ParallelLText{\story{Ijip Adet Pen Nangkechevoi}}{\story{The Return from Egypt}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{19}Herod thilot aphi Ijip adet Hemphu apherangke Joseph aphan amang pen cheklangsi pulo.  }{\jverse{19}When Herod died, an angel of the Lord suddenly appeared in a dream to Joseph in Egypt and said, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{20}“Thurra oso lapen apei aphan cheponra Israel adet chevoinon, pima kepathijisi oso aphan keri atum thitang-lo.”  }{\jverse{20}“Get up, take the child and his mother, and go to the land of Israel, for those who were seeking the child’s life are dead.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{21}Lapen alangli thursi oso lapen apei aphan cheponsi Israel adet chevoilo. }{\jverse{21}Then Joseph got up, took the child and his mother, and went to the land of Israel. }

 \end{document}
```

Output :[image]

Comment: Normally one would use `\needspace{2\baselineskip}`.  The tricky bit is not putting a gap at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It turns out that paracol has its own version of needspace.  (When all else fails, read the manual!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revised the solution to use `\ensurevspace`.  I had to make some major changes to `\ParallelLText` (like getting rid of those `\noindent`s which were causing me so much grief).

I assumed that the design philosophy was to allow `\jverse` and `\story` to be used independently of paracol, so added `\storygap` to handle `\ensurevspace`.

However, `\vfill` is still not working right.  The best way to fix it would be inside paracol's `\pcol@output`, which is beyond me.

```
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,11pt,openany]{book}

 \usepackage[margin=1.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{titletoc} %%% Table of contents 
 \usepackage{ebgaramond}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{paracol}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark} %% display chapter in header
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
   \fancyhead[C]{\thepage} %% To display numbering on every page alternately left and right

 \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
 \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
 \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
 \usepackage[colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}

 %%%% End Add
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand\versenumcolor{red}
 \newcommand\chapnumcolor{red}
 \renewcommand\paragraph{%
   \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                 {.25ex \@plus.25ex \@minus.1ex}%
                 {-.5em}%
                 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{\versenumcolor}}}%
 \newlength{\biblechapskip}
   \setlength{\biblechapskip}{1em plus .33em minus .2em}
 \newcounter{biblechapter}
 \newcounter{bibleverse}[biblechapter]
 \renewcommand\chaptername{Book}
 \let\ltx@chapter=\chapter
 \let\ltx@paragraph=\paragraph
 \newcommand{\book}[1]{%
   \gdef\currbook{#1}
   \ltx@chapter{#1}}
 \newcount\biblechap@svdopt
 \newenvironment{biblechapter}[1][\thebiblechapter]
   {\biblechap@svdopt=#1
   \ifnum\c@biblechapter=\biblechap@svdopt\else
     \advance\biblechap@svdopt by -1\fi
   \setcounter{biblechapter}{\the\biblechap@svdopt}
   \refstepcounter{biblechapter}
   \lettrine{\color{\chapnumcolor}\lower-6pt\hbox{\thebiblechapter}}{}\ignorespaces}
   {\vspace{\biblechapskip}}
 \renewcommand{\verse}[1][\thebibleverse]{%
   \refstepcounter{bibleverse}
   \markright{{\scshape\currbook} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}
   \ifnum\c@bibleverse=1\else
     \ltx@paragraph*{#1}\fi}%
 \makeatother


 \newcounter{jChapter}
 \newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{
 \noindent\scalebox{2.5}{\color{red}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.3mm}}
 \setcounter{jChapter}{#1}
 }  
 \newcommand{\jverse}[1]{\noindent\textcolor{cyan}{\scalebox{1.0}{\textbf{#1\hspace{1.0mm}}}}\markboth{\scshape Mathiu\ \thejChapter : #1}{} }
 \newcommand{\story}[1]{\vfill\noindent\parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{\centering\it\textbf{#1}}}% \centering contained within \parbox

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\storygap}{\vfill\ensurevspace{3\baselineskip}\switchcolumn*}% paracol specific code
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \title{Translation}
 \date{}
 \author{}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \newcommand{\BookLine}{ \centering\noindent\rule{19cm}{1pt}}
 \newcommand{\BookNote}[1]{{\begin{center} \textbf{KEPACHINI} \justify

 #1
 \end{center}
 \BookLine
 \vspace{2mm}
 }}

 \newcommand{\ParallelLText}[2]{\switchcolumn[0] #1\par \switchcolumn[1] #2\par \switchcolumn*}

 \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} %%% To restart footnote numbering on every new pages

 \usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}

 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %set depth of printed table of contets.

 \makeatletter


 \patchcmd{\l@section}
   {\hfil}
   {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep     mu$}\hfill}
   {}{}

 \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
     \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname
         \@mkboth{%
            \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
     \printlist{toc}{}{}
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \end{multicols}%
     }

 \makeatother %print dots in sections in toc.


 \begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}

 \frontmatter
 \maketitle
 {\setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Barim\hfill~\\[2.5ex] }
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \tableofcontents
 }
 \mainmatter

 {\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \part*{\scshape Kechejok Barim}
 }
 \pagenumbering{arabic}  
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
 \setcounter{page}{1}



 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}

 \clearpage
 \setcounter{page}{1}


 {\pagestyle{empty}
 {\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \part*{\scshape Kechejok Kemi}
 }

 \frontmatter
 \setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Kemi\hfill~\\[2.0em]}
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \tableofcontents

 \mainmatter
 }
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
 \begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{4}Alangli det adang kurusar kethe lapen aron thekser atum aphan pangrumpetsi arjulo, “Khristo pirthe kehacheji adim kodakma?” }{\jverse{4}and calling together all the chief priests and scribes of the people, he inquired of them where the Messiah was to be born. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{5}Latum alangliphan thaksi pulo, “Ha Judia adet, Bethlehem arongsopi along. Pima ha montri ketok tekang lapuson helo; }{\jverse{5}They told him, “In Bethlehem of Judea; for so it has been written by the prophet: }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{6}‘Judia adet a-Bethlehem, nanglike Judia adet kedo arongsopi kethe hei hei angbong akebineilo, lapu kali; pima nangli pen keja abang vangji, alangli ne rat, Israel aphan pangriji.’ ” }{\jverse{6}‘And you, Bethlehem, in the land of Judah, are by no means least among the rulers of Judah; for from you shall come a ruler who is to shepherd my people Israel.’” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{7}     Ansi Herod kethek kere atum aphan hangjoisi halabangso achiklo-longso keklangcheng ahut alamjir arju pamelo.  }{\jverse{7}Then Herod secretly called for the wise men and learned from them the exact time when the star had appeared. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{8}Lapen latum aphan ha Bethlehem toisi pulo, “Damra labangso a-oso aphan ridam pamenon. Lapen nanglitum la thekdam long-lote neli jokta damsi kardomkhrup thekji aphan neli long chevoira nethan thunon.”  }{\jverse{8}Then he sent them to Bethlehem, saying, “Go and search diligently for the child; and when you have found him, bring me word so that I may also go and pay him homage.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{9}Latum recho alam arjudetsi damlo, lapen latum la keklangcheng ahut kethek-long achiklolongso latum aphrang aphrang damthusi hala oso kedo adim angdenchit an kele pen sangkok ketik ke dambomlo.  }{\jverse{9}When they had heard the king, they set out; and there, ahead of them, went the star that they had seen at its rising, until it stopped over the place where the child was. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{10}Halatum chiklolongso thek-longsi aning arong parpik-lo.  }{\jverse{10}When they saw that the star had stopped, they were overwhelmed with joy. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{11}Latum hem lut damsi oso lapen apei Meri aphan thek-long-lo, lapen latum akengphu patongruisi alangliphan ardomlo. Ansi latum akhi atelup chepursi alangliphan ning keme pen ser, hijung aphik lapen kenempru ajangthu adan hei hei pilo.  }{\jverse{11}On entering the house, they saw the child with Mary his mother; and they knelt down and paid him homage. Then, opening their treasure chests, they offered him gifts of gold, frankincense, and myrrh. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{12}Lapen Herod along damthuri pu Arnam ahukum amang pen longthusi latum atovar kaprek pen amethang adet chevoijuilo. }{\jverse{12}And having been warned in a dream not to return to Herod, they left for their own country by another road. }
 \storygap
 \ParallelLText{\story{Ijip Adet Kekat}}{\story{The Escape to Egypt}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{13}Latum chevoidet pen mamat Hemphu apherangke Joseph aphan amang pen cheklangsi pulo, “Thurra oso lapen apei aphan cheponra ha Ijip adet katnon, lapen neli nangliphan pupetik ke hadak-le donon; pima Herod ke kepavirjisi oso aphan riji dokdok-lo.”  }{\jverse{13}Now after they had left, an angel of the Lord appeared to Joseph in a dream and said, “Get up, take the child and his mother, and flee to Egypt, and remain there until I tell you; for Herod is about to search for the child, to destroy him.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{14}Alangli thursi ajo amat oso lapen apei aphan cheponsi Ijip adet kat-lo,  }{\jverse{14}Then Joseph got up, took the child and his mother by night, and went to Egypt, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{15}lapen Herod thithetik an latum hadaksi dobomlo. Lake Hemphu pen ajok ha montri kepu tekang, “Neli neli sopo aphan Ijip adet pen hang-lo,” pu alam kechekokji aphanlo. }{\jverse{15}and remained there until the death of Herod. This was to fulfill what had been spoken by the Lord through the prophet, “Out of Egypt I have called my son.” }
 \storygap
 \ParallelLText{\story{Bethlehem A-osomar Atum Aphan Kepathi}}{\story{The Massacre of the Infants}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{16}Ansi kethek kere atum alangliphan pachereitang-lo pu chinisi Herod jasemet aning thilo, lapen alangli Bethlehem lapen adung arei kedo ningkan hini arta lapen ningkan hini pen kekom arta pinso a-osomar atum aphan kepavirkoiji ahukum pilo lake alangli alangli long kevang-akethek kere atum pen chiklolongso keklang alamjir karjulong ahut ateng pensi klemlo.  }{\jverse{16}When Herod saw that he had been tricked by the wise men, he was infuriated, and he sent and killed all the children in and around Bethlehem who were two years old or under, according to the time that he had learned from the wise men. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{17}Ansi Jeremiah montri kepu alam chekok-lo, atheke alangli pulo: }{\jverse{17}Then was fulfilled what had been spoken through the prophet Jeremiah: }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{18}“Ha Ramah angbong ne kechiru chernap ase arjulong-lo; Rachel amethang asomar atum pen apot chiru chernap-lo; alangli aning kepliji aning hanghelo, athema halatum thikoilo.” }{\jverse{18}“A voice was heard in Ramah, wailing and loud lamentation,Rachel weeping for her children; she refused to be consoled, because they are no more.” }
 \storygap
 \ParallelLText{\story{Ijip Adet Pen Nangkechevoi}}{\story{The Return from Egypt}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{19}Herod thilot aphi Ijip adet Hemphu apherangke Joseph aphan amang pen cheklangsi pulo.  }{\jverse{19}When Herod died, an angel of the Lord suddenly appeared in a dream to Joseph in Egypt and said, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{20}“Thurra oso lapen apei aphan cheponra Israel adet chevoinon, pima kepathijisi oso aphan keri atum thitang-lo.”  }{\jverse{20}“Get up, take the child and his mother, and go to the land of Israel, for those who were seeking the child’s life are dead.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{21}Lapen alangli thursi oso lapen apei aphan cheponsi Israel adet chevoilo. }{\jverse{21}Then Joseph got up, took the child and his mother, and went to the land of Israel. }
\end{paracol}

 \end{document}
```

---

This solution use tikzpagenodes to compute the space remaining on the page, and uses ths information to implement a custom `\vfill`.  However, paracol requires a minimum space at the bottom of page in order to start a column, and `\needspace` MUST be run at the bottom of the page, not the top of the next page, so a small gap at the bottom of each page is inevitable.

Note that it take 3 runs (4 for stability) for this to work.  Two runs for tikz to compute the space, and another to send the imformation back to the previous calls to `\needspace` on this page.

```
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,11pt,openany]{book}

 \usepackage[margin=1.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{titletoc} %%% Table of contents 
 \usepackage{ebgaramond}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{paracol}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark} %% display chapter in header
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
   \fancyhead[C]{\thepage} %% To display numbering on every page alternately left and right

 \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
 \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
 \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
 \usepackage[colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}

 %%%% End Add
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand\versenumcolor{red}
 \newcommand\chapnumcolor{red}
 \renewcommand\paragraph{%
   \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                 {.25ex \@plus.25ex \@minus.1ex}%
                 {-.5em}%
                 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{\versenumcolor}}}%
 \newlength{\biblechapskip}
   \setlength{\biblechapskip}{1em plus .33em minus .2em}
 \newcounter{biblechapter}
 \newcounter{bibleverse}[biblechapter]
 \renewcommand\chaptername{Book}
 \let\ltx@chapter=\chapter
 \let\ltx@paragraph=\paragraph
 \newcommand{\book}[1]{%
   \gdef\currbook{#1}
   \ltx@chapter{#1}}
 \newcount\biblechap@svdopt
 \newenvironment{biblechapter}[1][\thebiblechapter]
   {\biblechap@svdopt=#1
   \ifnum\c@biblechapter=\biblechap@svdopt\else
     \advance\biblechap@svdopt by -1\fi
   \setcounter{biblechapter}{\the\biblechap@svdopt}
   \refstepcounter{biblechapter}
   \lettrine{\color{\chapnumcolor}\lower-6pt\hbox{\thebiblechapter}}{}\ignorespaces}
   {\vspace{\biblechapskip}}
 \renewcommand{\verse}[1][\thebibleverse]{%
   \refstepcounter{bibleverse}
   \markright{{\scshape\currbook} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}
   \ifnum\c@bibleverse=1\else
     \ltx@paragraph*{#1}\fi}%
 \makeatother


 \newcounter{jChapter}
 \newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{
 \noindent\scalebox{2.5}{\color{red}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.3mm}}
 \setcounter{jChapter}{#1}
 }  
 \newcommand{\jverse}[1]{\noindent\textcolor{cyan}{\scalebox{1.0}{\textbf{#1\hspace{1.0mm}}}}\markboth{\scshape Mathiu\ \thejChapter : #1}{} }
 \newcommand{\story}[1]{\needspace{3\baselineskip}\noindent\parbox[b]{\columnwidth}{\centering\it\textbf{#1}}}% \centering contained within \parbox

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\need@space}% reserve global register
\newcounter{need@space}[page]
\newcommand{\needspace}[1]{% #1 = space ndeded
  \vskip-\topskip\tikz[remember picture]{%
    \pgfextracty{\need@space}{\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{south}}%
    \global\need@space=-\need@space}%
  \hrule height0pt
  \ifdim\need@space>#1\relax% add space here
    \stepcounter{need@space}%
    \@ifundefined{need@space\thepage}{\vfill}{\vspace{\csname need@space\thepage\endcsname}}
  \else% break page here
    \ifnum\c@need@space>0
      \advance\need@space by -\topskip% leave room for \needspace
      \divide\need@space by \c@need@space
      \@ifundefined{need@space\thepage}{}{\dimen0=\csname need@space\thepage\endcsname
        \ifdim\need@space=\dimen0\else \advance\need@space by \dimen0\fi}%
      \protected@write{\@auxout}{}{\string\newneedspace{\the\need@space}{\thepage}}%
    \fi
    \pagebreak
  \fi}
\newcommand{\newneedspace}[2]% #1=fill space, #2=page number
  {\expandafter\gdef\csname need@space#2\endcsname{#1}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \title{Translation}
 \date{}
 \author{}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \newcommand{\BookLine}{ \centering\noindent\rule{19cm}{1pt}}
 \newcommand{\BookNote}[1]{{\begin{center} \textbf{KEPACHINI} \justify

 #1
 \end{center}
 \BookLine
 \vspace{2mm}
 }}

 \newcommand{\ParallelLText}[2]{\switchcolumn[0] #1\par \switchcolumn[1] #2\par \switchcolumn*}

 \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} %%% To restart footnote numbering on every new pages

 \usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}

 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %set depth of printed table of contets.

 \makeatletter
 \patchcmd{\l@section}
   {\hfil}
   {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep     mu$}\hfill}
   {}{}

 \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
     \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname
         \@mkboth{%
            \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
     \printlist{toc}{}{}
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \end{multicols}%
     }
 \makeatother %print dots in sections in toc.


 \begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}

 \frontmatter
 \maketitle
 {\setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Barim\hfill~\\[2.5ex] }
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \tableofcontents
 }
 \mainmatter

 {\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \part*{\scshape Kechejok Barim}
 }
 \pagenumbering{arabic}  
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
 \setcounter{page}{1}



 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}

 \clearpage
 \setcounter{page}{1}


 {\pagestyle{empty}
 {\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \part*{\scshape Kechejok Kemi}
 }

 \frontmatter
 \setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Kemi\hfill~\\[2.0em]}
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \tableofcontents

 \mainmatter
 }
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
 \begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{4}Alangli det adang kurusar kethe lapen aron thekser atum aphan pangrumpetsi arjulo, “Khristo pirthe kehacheji adim kodakma?” }{\jverse{4}and calling together all the chief priests and scribes of the people, he inquired of them where the Messiah was to be born. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{5}Latum alangliphan thaksi pulo, “Ha Judia adet, Bethlehem arongsopi along. Pima ha montri ketok tekang lapuson helo; }{\jverse{5}They told him, “In Bethlehem of Judea; for so it has been written by the prophet: }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{6}‘Judia adet a-Bethlehem, nanglike Judia adet kedo arongsopi kethe hei hei angbong akebineilo, lapu kali; pima nangli pen keja abang vangji, alangli ne rat, Israel aphan pangriji.’ ” }{\jverse{6}‘And you, Bethlehem, in the land of Judah, are by no means least among the rulers of Judah; for from you shall come a ruler who is to shepherd my people Israel.’” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{7}     Ansi Herod kethek kere atum aphan hangjoisi halabangso achiklo-longso keklangcheng ahut alamjir arju pamelo.  }{\jverse{7}Then Herod secretly called for the wise men and learned from them the exact time when the star had appeared. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{8}Lapen latum aphan ha Bethlehem toisi pulo, “Damra labangso a-oso aphan ridam pamenon. Lapen nanglitum la thekdam long-lote neli jokta damsi kardomkhrup thekji aphan neli long chevoira nethan thunon.”  }{\jverse{8}Then he sent them to Bethlehem, saying, “Go and search diligently for the child; and when you have found him, bring me word so that I may also go and pay him homage.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{9}Latum recho alam arjudetsi damlo, lapen latum la keklangcheng ahut kethek-long achiklolongso latum aphrang aphrang damthusi hala oso kedo adim angdenchit an kele pen sangkok ketik ke dambomlo.  }{\jverse{9}When they had heard the king, they set out; and there, ahead of them, went the star that they had seen at its rising, until it stopped over the place where the child was. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{10}Halatum chiklolongso thek-longsi aning arong parpik-lo.  }{\jverse{10}When they saw that the star had stopped, they were overwhelmed with joy. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{11}Latum hem lut damsi oso lapen apei Meri aphan thek-long-lo, lapen latum akengphu patongruisi alangliphan ardomlo. Ansi latum akhi atelup chepursi alangliphan ning keme pen ser, hijung aphik lapen kenempru ajangthu adan hei hei pilo.  }{\jverse{11}On entering the house, they saw the child with Mary his mother; and they knelt down and paid him homage. Then, opening their treasure chests, they offered him gifts of gold, frankincense, and myrrh. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{12}Lapen Herod along damthuri pu Arnam ahukum amang pen longthusi latum atovar kaprek pen amethang adet chevoijuilo. }{\jverse{12}And having been warned in a dream not to return to Herod, they left for their own country by another road. }
 \ParallelLText{\story{Ijip Adet Kekat}}{\story{The Escape to Egypt}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{13}Latum chevoidet pen mamat Hemphu apherangke Joseph aphan amang pen cheklangsi pulo, “Thurra oso lapen apei aphan cheponra ha Ijip adet katnon, lapen neli nangliphan pupetik ke hadak-le donon; pima Herod ke kepavirjisi oso aphan riji dokdok-lo.”  }{\jverse{13}Now after they had left, an angel of the Lord appeared to Joseph in a dream and said, “Get up, take the child and his mother, and flee to Egypt, and remain there until I tell you; for Herod is about to search for the child, to destroy him.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{14}Alangli thursi ajo amat oso lapen apei aphan cheponsi Ijip adet kat-lo,  }{\jverse{14}Then Joseph got up, took the child and his mother by night, and went to Egypt, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{15}lapen Herod thithetik an latum hadaksi dobomlo. Lake Hemphu pen ajok ha montri kepu tekang, “Neli neli sopo aphan Ijip adet pen hang-lo,” pu alam kechekokji aphanlo. }{\jverse{15}and remained there until the death of Herod. This was to fulfill what had been spoken by the Lord through the prophet, “Out of Egypt I have called my son.” }
 \ParallelLText{\story{Bethlehem A-osomar Atum Aphan Kepathi}}{\story{The Massacre of the Infants}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{16}Ansi kethek kere atum alangliphan pachereitang-lo pu chinisi Herod jasemet aning thilo, lapen alangli Bethlehem lapen adung arei kedo ningkan hini arta lapen ningkan hini pen kekom arta pinso a-osomar atum aphan kepavirkoiji ahukum pilo lake alangli alangli long kevang-akethek kere atum pen chiklolongso keklang alamjir karjulong ahut ateng pensi klemlo.  }{\jverse{16}When Herod saw that he had been tricked by the wise men, he was infuriated, and he sent and killed all the children in and around Bethlehem who were two years old or under, according to the time that he had learned from the wise men. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{17}Ansi Jeremiah montri kepu alam chekok-lo, atheke alangli pulo: }{\jverse{17}Then was fulfilled what had been spoken through the prophet Jeremiah: }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{18}“Ha Ramah angbong ne kechiru chernap ase arjulong-lo; Rachel amethang asomar atum pen apot chiru chernap-lo; alangli aning kepliji aning hanghelo, athema halatum thikoilo.” }{\jverse{18}“A voice was heard in Ramah, wailing and loud lamentation,Rachel weeping for her children; she refused to be consoled, because they are no more.” }
 \ParallelLText{\story{Ijip Adet Pen Nangkechevoi}}{\story{The Return from Egypt}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{19}Herod thilot aphi Ijip adet Hemphu apherangke Joseph aphan amang pen cheklangsi pulo.  }{\jverse{19}When Herod died, an angel of the Lord suddenly appeared in a dream to Joseph in Egypt and said, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{20}“Thurra oso lapen apei aphan cheponra Israel adet chevoinon, pima kepathijisi oso aphan keri atum thitang-lo.”  }{\jverse{20}“Get up, take the child and his mother, and go to the land of Israel, for those who were seeking the child’s life are dead.” }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{21}Lapen alangli thursi oso lapen apei aphan cheponsi Israel adet chevoilo. }{\jverse{21}Then Joseph got up, took the child and his mother, and went to the land of Israel. }
\end{paracol}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Yes its working! but it creating some space for every pages from bottom. @John Kormylo